# Does the VS Code extension debugger have a REPL?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm writing a VS Code extension starting from the `generator-code` template and I'm using the [integrated debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension#debugging-the-extension) to run the extension.

Is there a way to run JavaScript code on the fly in the extension like you can in regular browsers and Chrome/web extensions? Does VS Code have an interactive "console" that has access to my specific extension APIs and globals?

Comment: the `DEBUG CONSOLE` of the VSC launching the extension Host when you hit a breakpoint

Comment: That would seem obvious but there's no `vscode` namespace and [`import('vscode')` doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GFep.png), so it's unclear how this can be useful. I'd like to use this console to test out `vscode` API

Comment: work with it like you do the Browser console. on a break point you can inspect/manipulate variables, I have `vscode` imported/required and I even get completions in `vscode.`, also on object properties

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has, once you set breakpoint in debugger and open output tab then bottom of output has the option to run code just like console.log